# Ubuntu wifi ethernet not working

Tags: wireless

I tried following commands but its not working, my system is 14e4:4315. can someone help please. Thanks!

lspci -nn | grep 0280
The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with '\'. Is this your device?

Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
If so, then bcmwl-kernel-source is correct for your device. If you still have the install DVD or USB, then you can find it and its prerequisite there. Navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag and drop the deb file to your desktop. Now navigate to pool > main > d > dkms and drag and drop dkms to your desktop. Now install both with:

cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Load the driver:

sudo modprobe wl

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu Run type Additional drivers then the drivers search windows will show up with a list of drivers missing from your system and the same list contains drivers compatible to your system, choose the recommended one and install it, then restart system and see if it's working.
Remember to include Canonical partners and Independent for other upgrade resources in the software and updates options.